# Javascript function in Partial view can't access Javascript variable defined in page (MVC 3)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to learn to use Knockoutjs but I am facing a problem

this is the scenario:

I have a page where I define a Knockoutjs viewModel as follow

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = {
        selectedColumns: ko.observableArray()
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Now with an Ajax request I add to the page a checkbox which I want to bind to the viewModel

```
<input type='checkbox' id='someId' data-bind='attr: { value: 'someValue' }, checked: $root.selectedColumns'>

 $(document).ready(function() {
                 ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById(someId));
            });
```

but I always get

Error: ReferenceError: viewModel is not defined
Source File: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

I've created a test page where everything is on one page and it works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var count = 0;
        var viewModel = {
            selectedPeople: ko.observableArray()
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });

        function AddAnotherCheckbox(){

            var id = "checkbox" + count;

            var checknox = count + "   <input type='checkbox' id='" + id + "' data-bind='attr: { value: \"" + count + "\" }, checked: $root.selectedPeople'><br/>";

            $("#container").append(checknox);
            count++;

             $(document).ready(function() {
                 ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById(id));
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
    <body>

        <input type="button" onclick="AddAnotherCheckbox()"/>

        <div id="container"></div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <span data-bind="text: selectedPeople"></span> 
    </body>
</html>
```

But I  can't make it working using partial view

Could you explain to me what's the problem and how can I solve it?

thanks

Comment: A bunch of stuff off here. If selectedPeople is an array, what would you expect data-bind="text: selectedPeople " to display? Why are you treating it like a boolean elsewhere: "checked: $root.selectedPeople"?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Description

This is not about Knockout, it's about JavaScript in general.
Your Testcode works because you have defined the `viewModel` outside of `$(document).ready`

This is a other scope.

Compare theese to jsFiddles

- [This does not work](http://jsfiddle.net/YeJLs/2/) (your scenario)
- [This works](http://jsfiddle.net/YeJLs/1/)

#### Sample

**This does not work**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = {
        someThing : "Test"
    };
});

$(document).ready(function () {  
    alert(viewModel.someThing);
});
```

**This will work**

```
var viewModel;
$(document).ready(function () {
    viewModel = {
        someThing : "Test"
    };
});

$(document).ready(function () {   
    alert(viewModel.someThing);
});
```

#### More Information

- [Explaining JavaScript Scope And Closures](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/)

​

Comment: Your are the king of the jungle!! :)  Thanks